# retrieve data send from post ajax req

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, struts

I need to send large amount of string in a ajax post request to server. If i add it the end of the url, i can get using request.getParameter() method in the server.

But i can't append large string in the url.So i want to send using the method send() of XMLHttpRequest instead of appending it to url.

But i couldn't retrieve the same using request.getParameter() in server.

How to retrieve data send from ajax request in j2ee server?
Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an ajax intensive webapp, I would suggest using a javascript library (such as jquery) to handle ajax.  In jQuery, you could do this as :

```
$.post("your_url.php", { param1: "value1", param2: "value2" } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether you are or arent using AJAX, there are limits to the actual length of the Url which changes [browser to browser](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html).

It will be better `POST` all your data. Below is the code to do the same using AJAX:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Get the correct http object depending on browser
var url = "YOUR_URL.php";
var params = "param1=value1&param2=value2";
http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() { // Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(params);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: BTW... you will not be able to retrieve all your variables using `request.getParameter("param1");` etc.